# How to run a graph in Tensorflow more effectively?

Tags: tensorflow

How can I run a saved model of Tensorflow more effectively without restarting its operations?? 
every time I call the predict method it takes time to get the score result.

```
def predict(self, msg):
tensor = self._convector.sentence_to_id_vector(msg)
if tensor is 0:
    return 0
else:
    graph = tf.Graph()
    with graph.as_default():
        sess = tf.Session()
        saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph("{}/model.ckpt.meta".format(self._model_dir))
        saver.restore(sess, ("{}/model.ckpt".format(self._model_dir)))
        input = graph.get_operation_by_name('input').outputs[0]
        seq_len = graph.get_operation_by_name('lengths').outputs[0]
        dropout_keep_prob = graph.get_operation_by_name('dropout_keep_prob').outputs[0]
        prediction = graph.get_operation_by_name('final_layer/softmax/predictions').outputs[0]
        model_seq_len = self._convector.sequence_len
        sample_len = self._convector.sample_len

        score = sess.run(prediction, feed_dict={input: tensor.reshape(1, model_seq_len),
                                                seq_len: [sample_len], dropout_keep_prob: 1.0})
        print('score result: [{0:.2f}, {1:.2f}]'.format(score[0, 0], score[0, 1]))
        return score
```

Answer (score 0):

You are importing the graph and session every time you run the prediction.

Save the graph and session in memory (keep them available, in an object or a global variable). Running a new prediction you should only have to execute `sess.run` line.

You currently run 1 prediction at a time. Matrix multiplications internal to the model are executed more efficiently if you run a bunch requests at the same time (basically batching for predictions). This is not always possible to do, but it does provide good performance as long as you can fit the execution in memory.

You import the model from the checkpoint. That might include operation placement that was good for training, but maybe not ideal for prediction. Use the saved_model export functionality and it will clear it, allowing the client to pick best placement. This should allow you to make proper use of the GPU. As a side effect it will store for you the names of the input and output tensors so that you don't need to hard-code them.

Finally, make sure you have the right version of tensorflow. The basic one doesn't have GPU support or even AVX2 support (special instructions on modern CPUs). Depending on the model and workload they might a small or a big make a difference.